# Why does resolve not return json?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

When resolving getBody() of a CfnRestApi construct using AWS CDK in Java

```
  CfnRestApi C
  LOG.debug(this.resolve(C.getBody()));
```

The output is as follows which seems close to JSON, but is not.

```
{swagger=2.0, info={description=API to return Car Image, version=1.0.0, title=Get_Car API}, schemes=[https], paths={/={}, /get_car={post={produces=[application/json, application/customer-error, application/api_not_found, application/no_record, application/api_error], responses={200={description=200 response, schema={$ref=#/definitions/Empty}}, 201={description=201 response}, 204={description=204 response}, 230={description=230 response}, 231={description=231 response}, 232={description=232 response}, 233={description=233 response}}, security=[{sigv4=[]}], x-amazon-apigateway-integration={responses={default={statusCode=200}}, uri={Fn::Join=[:, [arn:aws:apigateway, {Ref=AWS::Region}, lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda, {Ref=AWS::Region}, {Ref=AWS::AccountId}, function, {Fn::Join=[, [{Ref=APIFunction}, /invocations]]}]]}, passthroughBehavior=when_no_match, httpMethod=POST, contentHandling=CONVERT_TO_TEXT, credentials={Fn::GetAtt=[IAMAPIServiceRole, Arn]}, type=aws}}}}, securityDefinitions={sigv4={type=apiKey, name=Authorization, in=header, x-amazon-apigateway-authtype=awsSigv4}}, definitions={Empty={type=object, title=Empty Schema}}}
```

Is there any way to retrieve `getBody()` as JSON or can the above output be parsed like JSON somehow such that I can traverse the contents and reference nodes by name?

Additionally I've tried this.toJsonString(C.getBody()) but this returns a token ${Token[TOKEN.221]}

As well I've tried parsing the object with jackson

```java
outputJson(C.getBody());

public String outputJson(Object obj) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
    LOG.debug("outputJson");
    ObjectMapper jsonWriter = new ObjectMapper();
    return jsonWriter.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
}
```

Which return the following

> Error: No serializer found for class software.amazon.jsii.JsiiObject
> and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid
> exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)

Note that calling outputJson(this.toJsonString(C.getBody()) also returns a token ${Token[TOKEN.221]} so it's clear that the json is a token.

Comment: This looks like the `toString()` output of the object in question (which is custom written or possibly generated), it is intended for debugging purposes, not as a serialization format. If you want JSON, you need to use a JSON serializer like Jackson or Gson.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel is it common practice for a Library to serialize an Object with toString() as text output in this manner? I'm not familiar enough in this regard. Thanks Conteh.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Are there common conventions to be clear at the code level that an Object is JSON parseable string content?

Comment: No, you use a library like Jackson and Gson, not a `toString()` if you want to produce JSON output. `toString` is - usually - intended for debugging purposes. What happens is that `LOG.debug(object)` will call to `toString()` of the object.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel I've updated the question. The json that returns is a token.